# Is there an app in linux similar to Shazam?

Tags: sound, music

Does anyone know if there's an app in linux that works like Shazam that tells you the title and artist of a song that's playing?

Comment: Yes, `amorak`  did that, and had the option to have it display the lyrics too... however this isn't a linux support site so why ask here?  I don't see anything on-topic (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) where SE *Unix & Linux* would be more appropriate given how you've worded your question.

Comment: Sorry but I'm unaware of other sites to ask questions like this. What is Ask Ubuntu for? Is it only for Ubuntu technical questions?

Comment: Pretty much yes, Ubuntu Forums caters for other opinion/subjective questions that are off-topic here, but you're question doesn't even appear to even be about Ubuntu, avoiding any specifics as to if you're asking about a device/appliance release of Ubuntu, a server releases of Ubuntu, or other.  Ubuntu has various releases and you've given nothing specific, except the term Linux which SE covers on another site.

Comment: I tried Ubuntu One. I know I've been on the site before but the password I remember using didn't work. So I selected 'Forgot Your Password' and it came up with: This email address is however not associated with any Ubuntu One accounts. If you want to create a new Ubuntu One account using this email address, please go to:
https://login.ubuntu.com/+new_account

Comment: Ubuntu ONE is an SSO (*single-sign-on*) service, ie. it's how I'm logged and accessing this web site (askubuntu.com; I'm not going thru SE so can't go outside askubuntu.com, not even to chat which is on SE itself).  It also lets me access launchpad, iso.qa & other Ubuntu web sites.  Ubuntu ONE once-upon-a-time provided file-storage & other services, but that ended years ago; the SSO (*single-sign-on* service only remains. Ubuntu Forums is https://ubuntuforums.org/  (which will use Ubuntu SSO or Ubuntu-One to login too; possibly others too; I use my Ubuntu SSO which is via Ubuntu-ONE)